# What's the URL to redeem iOS App Store promo codes

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, promotion-code, in-app-promotions

I'd like to be able to generate links that allow users of my iOS app to redeem promo codes for in app purchases. So, they might receive an email with a button that says, "Redeem Code" that takes them to the app store redemption page with the code prefilled, or redeems it for them. However, I've been unable to find the correct url for this.

A related question has an answer for mac store apps, but it doesn't work for iOS codes: [URL for redeeming Mac App Store promo codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8623275/url-for-redeeming-mac-app-store-promo-codes)

Answer (score 15):

`https://apps.apple.com/redeem?code=` (ABM Code Redemption Link)

It works for me.

Answer (score 7):

To open the redeem page of the App Store use the following link:

> itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/freeProductCodeWizard?code=YOUR_CODE

**EDIT**:
As Kamil Rykowski pointed out the above url only works till iOS 13. Since iOS 14 (also works for iOS 13) you have to use

> itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=YOUR_CODE

Comment: The link worked fine on iOS 13, but after upgrading to iOS 14 it stopped working. The App Store just displays an error page. It's definitely about iOS version, nothing else changed.

Comment: What is MZFinance?

Comment: It is part of the App Store and I think it is responsible for processing payments and everything around that (like handling payment info, subscription management, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Short link also works:
https://apple.co/2RtWNMU?code=YOUR_CODE

Short link source - App Store help page
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201209
Link "Redeem your gift card"

Answer (score 3):

The "official" Offer Code URL is displayed on the offer details page in App Store Connect:

1. In App Store Connect open your app and select In-App Purchases -> Manage.
2. Under "In-App Purchases" select your in-app purchase.
3. Under "Subscription Prices" expand "Active Subscription Offers" and click the offer name in the list.
4. The Offer Code URL is shown on this page, for example:

https://apps.apple.com/redeem?ctx=offercodes&id=APP_ID&code=CODE

where APP_ID is your application ID and CODE is the code to redeem.

I guess it is not safe to assume the URL format will always be the same. So you should check the current valid URL for your offer from the offer details page.

Comment: Promotion codes and Offer codes are two different things, the questions was regarding promotion codes, but this answer is for offer codes.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But to avoid even more confusion, you should use the term "Promo code" and not "Promotion code". Apple's documentation uses that term. I thought Promo codes were replaced by Offer codes, but they seem to exist still. I have used also Promo codes earlier, but moved to more flexible Offer codes. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me is:

iOS 13:

> itms-apps://apps.apple.com/account/freeProductCodeWizard?code=YOUR_CODE

iOS 14:

> itms-apps://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/freeProductCodeWizard?code=YOUR_CODE

Not sure about previous iOS versions, probably using the iOS 13 format, but didn't test it due to lack of appropriate devices.

Comment: What is MZFinance? Id be careful about using this link, unless someone knows what that is

Answer (score 0):

As of the latest iOS 15.2.1, all of the above solutions now longer work. Users will get taken to the AppStore but it will give them a blank screen that says "Failed to Connect"

However, I found a updated link that gets the job done, in fact, it's a little nicer now in my opinion...

```
"https://apps.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/redeemLandingPage?code=" + redemptionCode
```